# How to check all checkbox with the same value from another column

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm trying to check all checkbox for each `row` on my table when my `Dropdown menu` value is `Sent` and the value of `Status Column` is equal to `Sent`. I'm now able to check/uncheck all checkbox on my table. But now I need to check all those status is `Sent` when the dropdown menu is also `Sent`. I appreciate all answers. Please check my code below. Thanks a lot

**view.html**

```
                   <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Status</strong></td>

                    </tr>
                   </thead>

               <tbody> <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td value="Sent">Sent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td value="Created">Created</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td value="Created">Created</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td value="Sent">Sent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td value="Sent">Sent</td>
                </tr> </tbody>

               <select class="form-control" id="default-select">

              <option value="delete">Created</option>
              <option value="stored">Stored Status</option>
              <option value="sent">Sent Status</option>
                                  </select>
```

**script.js**

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    if($('#default-select option:selected').val() == 'sent'){
    $('#testTable tbody input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
}});
```

Comment: try to replace `this.checked` with `$(this).is(":checked")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO ATTACHED : Updated After Request, THIS MIGHT HELP

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#default-select").on("change",function(){
    $("input").prop("checked",false);
       
 $("td").each(function(i,v){
 
 if($(this).text().trim() ==  $("#default-select").val()){
 
       $(this).closest("tr").find("input").prop("checked",true);
       }
 });

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All</strong></td>
                        <td><strong>Status</strong></td>

                    </tr>
                   </thead>

               <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>sent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td >created</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td >created</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>sent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td>sent</td>
                </tr> 
                 <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td>stored</td>
                </tr> 
                </tbody>
</table>
<select class="form-control" id="default-select">

              <option value="created">Created</option>
              <option value="stored">Stored Status</option>
              <option value="sent">Sent Status</option>
                                  </select>
```

Comment: awesome! but how can i do this by getting the `class` of checkbox, rather the `value`?

Comment: For that you can use $(this).attr("class") instead of $(this).val(), if this help please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry but how to do this by not setting the checkbox `value` to `sent`? because my checkbox have already a `value`

Comment: $("table input .sent").prop("checked",true); where sent is class of checkox and you can dynamically add class as i have already mentioned in the answer.

Comment: still not working `$("table input").prop("checked",false);//Make all checkbox false
$("table input .sent").prop("checked",true)`

Comment: can you update your code? so I'll can see my errors, pretty sure I'm doing it right

Answer (score 1):

This is the simpliest way i prefer to do. Check out the [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=f1fb3afa10cbe90f8f179162b2d1d03b). I gave clas to checkboxes and fired the function as you change the value of select, then check what the value is. if it is sent then click the class that i have created.

Comment: It working but only for 'sent'. If you want to add more filter than you need to define more var into the function and check the var with 'if else', I belive you have enough knowledge to do that.